# How to add an object containing an arraylist to another arraylist, C#?

Tags: c#, oop, object, arraylist, streamwriter

I am making a windows application in C# which reads in data about car hire companies from a text file and outputs the information in two listboxes (Companies and cars). there are 2 classes `Company` and `Cars` and they read into arrays as so:

```
 public void readFile()
    {
        string IDComp, compName, compAddress, compPost;
        int compNumCars;
        string IDcars, carsMM, carsReg, carsFuel, carsServ, carsComments;
        ArrayList carArray;


        //start streamreader (open file)
        StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(theFile);

        //read the file and bring in the data
        while (!readFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            //get raw company info  
            IDComp = readFile.ReadLine();
            compName = readFile.ReadLine();
            compAddress = readFile.ReadLine();
            compPost = readFile.ReadLine();
            compNumCars = Convert.ToInt32(readFile.ReadLine());

            //get car array read in for company 
            carArray = new ArrayList(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < compNumCars; i++)
            {
                //get car data
                IDcars = readFile.ReadLine();
                carsMM = readFile.ReadLine();
                carsReg = readFile.ReadLine();
                carsFuel = readFile.ReadLine();
                carsServ = readFile.ReadLine();
                carsComments = readFile.ReadLine();

                //create a car object
                Cars newCars = new Cars(IDcars, carsMM, carsReg, carsFuel, carsServ, carsComments);

                //add it to array
                carArray.Add(newCars);

            }   //car array done!


            //create a Company object
            Company newComp = new Company(IDComp, compName, compAddress, compPost, compNumCars, carArray);

            //add company object to array
            companyArray.Add(newComp);
        }
        readFile.Close();

    }
```

i have a working streamwriter and I can successfully edit information for existing cars and companies: (code to update listboxes not shown)

```
                                                             //SAVE EDIT

    private void btnsaveeditcomp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Company editcomp = (Company)companyArray[lstCompany.SelectedIndex];

        editcomp.setCompID(txtEditcompID.Text);
        editcomp.setName(txtEditName.Text);
        editcomp.setAddress(txtEditAddress.Text);
        editcomp.setPostcode(txtEditPost.Text);
        editcomp.setNumCars(Convert.ToInt32(txtEditNumCars.Text));

        updateSelectdComp();
        btnSaveEditComp.Hide();
        writeFile();


    }


    private void saveeditcars_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cars editCars = (Cars)carsArray[lstCars.SelectedIndex];
        ArrayList tmpCars = ((Company)companyArray[selectedComp]).getFleet();

        Cars newcars = (Cars)tmpCars[selectedCar];

        newcars.setCarsID(txtEditcarID.Text);
        newcars.setMakeModel(txtEditMM.Text);
        newcars.setReg(txtEditReg.Text);
        newcars.setFuel(txtEditFuel.Text);
        newcars.setServdate(txtEditServdate.Text);
        newcars.setComments(txtEditComments.Text);

        updateSelectedCar(); 
        btnSaveEditCars.Hide();
        writeFile();

    }
```

`Fleet` is an arraylist within the `Company` class which stores the information on each companies specific cars.

How can i ADD a new company object? the new company does't have to have any cars attatched to it initially and i will use the same textboxes as above `(txtEditcompID.Text, ect.)` to input the information for the Company i wish to create.

thank you for any help, it's much appreciated :)

Comment: You are used to program in Java, right? Avoid ArrayList and use generic lists instead, ArrayList is only preserved for compatibility.

Comment: i have never used java, i've just started c#,  am required to use arraylists unfortunatly

Comment: Then you're following very old documentation, ArrayList is deprecated in favor of generic Lists.

Comment: Since Gusman is being unhelpful, here's your solution:
Think of companies and cars as two separate things.  A `Company` object includes a list of cars which the company makes.  When you create a new `Company` add it to the list of companies with no cars.  Then, when you create a `Car` you can just add it to the appropriate `Company` list of Cars.  `ArrayList` has a method to add items to the end of the array and you can use that to do the append

Comment: thank you @RayFischer ! i'll be sure to do that :)